# Deleting similar lines of text using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a text file where I would like to remove any lines that contain similar text using Powershell.

An example of the text is

```
> *blah*1.my_parameter: 30
> *1.my_parameter: 40
> *blah*2.my_parameter: 30
> *2.my_parameter: 40
```

I want to keep

```
> *blah*1.my_parameter: 30
> *blah*2.my_parameter: 30
```

and remove

```
 > *1.my_parameter: 40
 > *2.my_parameter: 40
```

I've had good search already and found the -match and Get-Unique commands but nothing seems to work so far.
Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: The lines you want to remove always starts with * and a number and the other lines don’t?

Comment: Any particular reason you want to use Powershell for this?  Probably not the best tool for this sort of job.  Also as Doug said, you are going to have to give a clearer example and let us know the exact rules of matching and which one to retain, e.g.  is it the longer of the two where you have a partial match? How do we split the line to look for the part you wan to match on?  Also posting what you have so far, with an explanation of what doesn't work about it would improve the question

Comment: If your statement "lines that contain similar text" is true then every line should be kept, becuase all have similar patterns.

Comment: What I would like to do is to see that there are two lines of text that are the same between the last * and the : symbols. So in the example text lines 1 and 2 would be a match as they both contain 1.my_parameter. I then want to retain the longer line *blah*1.my_parameter and remove the shorter line *1.my_parameter. I'm using Powershell here as its part of a WPF that I've created. I'm open to suggestions of different tools for the job.

Comment: I suggest you name them something more meaningful and distinct than `*blah*2.my_parameter` and `*2.my_parameter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following would work but it would use a lot of memory on large input files.
The idea is to group all input on a matching regular expression, sort the groups on length and select the first one of the descending sorted results.

```
$reg = [Regex]::new('\*[\w.]+:')
Get-Content <testfile> | 
    Group-Object {([Regex]::Match($_, $reg)).Value} | 
    Select-Object Group |
    Foreach-Object {
        $_.Group | 
        Sort-Object -Descending $_.length | 
        Select-Object -First 1
    }
```

**Test**

```
$test = @(
    '> *blah*1.my_parameter: 30'
    , '> *1.my_parameter: 40'
    , '> *blah*2.my_parameter: 30'
    , '> *2.my_parameter: 40'
)

$reg = [Regex]::new('\*[\w.]+:')
$test | group {([Regex]::Match($_, $reg)).Value} | % {($_.group | sort le*)[-1]}
```

**Output**

```
> *blah*1.my_parameter: 30
> *blah*2.my_parameter: 30
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much. I've been looking at regex but still getting my head around how it works and this has helped a lot. I'm a self taught PowerShell user and have learned so much from the Stack Overflow community. I hope to one day have the knowledge to contribute as well

Comment: Your welcome. I just asked in [code golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/209557/96472) because I'm pretty sure that the syntax can still be shortened substantially but I can't shorten it any further myself.

Comment: @AnchorEyes - A whole lot shorter - `sort -d{$_.length} |sort -un{$_ -match'\*[\w.]+:';$matches[0]}`